# Create video with Flutter

Tags: ios, video, flutter

I am currently diving into mobile development for *iOS*, with the need of following task:

- Create a **video from a series of pictures**, probably with fade transitions and background music

I could not find any resources on that topic so far, in the context of Flutter. 
*Question*: Is it possible to create videos (as described in my task) with Flutter?

Comment: I don't see a reason to not. Probably you will have to render on the platform side by using [platform channels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). But other than that, all of the UI can be done with Flutter for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Did you have find any solutions?